# Google Sheets Script to regularly check status of URL and update cell accordingly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a particular case of a Google Sheet with tweet URLs. I am trying to come up with a Google Script to check the status of each tweet URL on a regular basis like a CHRON (once a day) and then update a cell with 3 possible options: `Active` (if the tweet is available), `Removed` (if the tweet was removed) and `Account Suspended` (if the account authoring the tweet was suspended). Then, in another cell, update the actual date when the script detected the change. In a case where the status of the tweet URL changed from `Active` to either `Removed` or `Account Suspended`, the CHRON script should stop checking that particular Tweet URL (to minimize the amount of requests sent by the table).

My table should ultimately look like this:

```
tweet URL                                                  | status            | change detected
-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------
https://twitter.com/NESST6/status/1208926911692337153      | Removed           | 01/01/2020
https://twitter.com/CEAS_CHOCHS/status/1210798889801936896 | Account Suspended | 02/01/2020
https://twitter.com/CremechocoS/status/1212816881670918149 | Active            |
```

Realizing that the `<title>` attribute of a live tweet will always return the **tweet text**, the `<title>` of a removed tweet will return **#N/A** and the `<title>` of a suspended account will return **Twitter / Account Suspended**, I have managed to achieve manual results by reading the `<title>` attribute of the HTML page of the tweet using the `IMPORTXML` formula as follows:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://twitter.com/NESST6/status/1208926911692337153", "//title")
```

However, I quickly realized that the `IMPORTXML` formula is not that reliable when it comes to fetching a large number of URLs.

I am curious whether a Google script that will function like a CHRON and do this automatically for every tweet URL in the table (new ones are added regularly), update the status, stop checking tweet URLs once their status has changed (skip it) and register the date when a status change was detected.

Would appreciate very much if anyone has already done similar things and/or can lend a hand.

Cheers,

Comment: I would recommend you write a GAS project that runs on a scheduled trigger and then goes through each row and makes the necessary `UrlFetch` calls to get the data you need. Have you looked into that?

Comment: I would very much like to test this with GAS but unfortunately I lack the necessary programming skills. Was hoping someone had already done it before :-(

Comment: Hello @EladRatson! Do you have some code snippets that you could **provide** that might be of help? What you are requesting is a bit broad, so any code snippets you can share, are very much appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: That is exactly my problem... I don't know how to code a script that will run on a scheduled trigger, go through each row and make the necessary 'UrlFetch' call to get the data and update the table accordingly.

Comment: @EladRatson, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service to write the answer for you but rather to help you fix issues and gain an understanding of what has gone wrong in your code. Therefore, I suggest you take a look at these links since they might help you in the future development of the script you want: 1 [Apps Script triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers); 2. [UrlFetchApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app); 3. [Apps Script Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).